# Data Fusion pipeline using external IP from Cloud NAT instead of assigning external IPs to the Dataproc cluster nodes

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I am trying to extract data from a client that restricts access by an external IP. I have already configured and tested a Cloud NAT with the allowed IP. But when I deploy my Pipeline, Data Fusion creates Dataproc cluster with assigning other temporary external IPs to the nodes. I would like not to assign these IPs so the nodes can use the defined IP on Cloud NAt.

I tried passing --no-address to Dataproc via Data Fusion runtime arguments, but it is not the right way. Also I looked up some way of configuring compute profile on my Data Fusion instance, which was not found anywhere either on Basic or Enterprise editions.

I would like to obtain a Cloud Data Fusion pipeline making connections to my client´s server using my Cloud NAT external IP insteand of assigning temporary IPs to the cluster which simply are not allowed on my clients firewall.

Answer (score 3):

Cloud Data Fusion does not support private access which restricts it from creating internal-ip only Dataproc cluster.

Support for private access is being worked on and will be available soon.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Customers are able to use Cloud NAT with Cloud Data Fusion while being able to access public IPs**

The confusion here is that during the building of the pipeline, in the Studio view and Validation stages, the connections are ran on a tenant project, which Cloud NAT isn't being applied. Errors are thrown at these stages because of inability to connect through the tenant project.

HOWEVER when the pipeline is deployed and you can officially Run the pipeline, this typically is happening on a Dataproc cluster in your own project, where Cloud NAT has been applied.

To get around the errors of the Studio and Validation stage and to get your pipeline to the Running state, by deploying it, you should substitute your connecting credentials in the Public IP plugin as Macros. The macros will be overlooked during validation stage allowing you successfully deploy and run the pipeline in a project where Cloud NAT is in effect.

Here are some links on how to set Macros:
https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/382043060/Using+macros+to+create+a+dynamic+data+pipeline
https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/reusable-pipeline

Here is a link to the CDAP bug tracking the failing of the Validation step:
https://cdap.atlassian.net/browse/PLUGIN-381

Comment: Thanks for your post. I am not working in this project anymore to confirm your answers. But I will keep it for whenever I face pipelines on Data fusion again.